# Need help reducing file size Photoshop, gimp, paint.net

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, file-format, paint.net

I have been asked to compress an image that will be used for mass email, the image is currently 628 KB and needs to be 50 KB maximum, I have been advised to use PNG files.

I have also been asked to do this using Photoshop, paint.net and GIMP 2.

Any advice on all three of these software's would be much appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: There are many very similar questions here on GD.SE, I'm sure you can use the search and find some good answers

Answer (score 4):

Depends a lot what the original image is (size and content).

If this is mostly a photo, then you have to use JPEG to get the file small, and file size will be a compromise between image size and quality (hint: in Gimp's advanced options, there is a "chroma subsampling" option which is what gives the more efficient size reduction for the smallest quality loss, so start there).

If it's CGI (text, logo) with large uniform areas, then PNG may be more efficient than JPEG. You can try to produce an indexed PNG (in Gimp: Image>Mode>Indexed before exporting to PNG).

Gimp has a "Save for web" plugin that lets you see what the final image looks like and how big the file is.

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time in Photoshop. The Save For Web allows you to adjust the quality of a JPG in order to reduce file size. For example, you may need to compress to a 50% quality to bring the file size to 49K. Photoshop also tells you what the final file size will be before hitting the final Save button.